# Why are we talking in statistics about random variables when talking of a sample, is it not "one" random variable?

Tags: statistics

a random variable is a mapping between the probability space to the real numbers.

When we are talking in statistics about a sample different random variables:

X_1, X_2, X_3 withX_1 = 5, X_2 = 6, X_3 = 7 in a particular sample (edited)

but i would argue, that X is just "one" random variable, why are we saying we have multiple random variables in statistics?

Comment: $P(X=2)=0.1$ means "The probability that the random variable X takes the value 2 is 0.1".  Then $P(X_1)$ means nothing as you have not given $X_1$ a value to have a probability of. Also, a probability can never be 5, 6, 7 though I guess you might mean $P(X_1 = 5)$. There is no problem about $P(X = 1), P(X = 2)...$ and so on for one variable $X$

Comment: I've answered because (I think that) I see your point, but I would still advise you to rewrite your second sentence. $P(X_1) = 5$ doesn't make sense. Either you mean "$X_1 = 5$" in a particular sample, or you mean "$P(X_1=5)$" which is the probability that variable $X_1$ takes value $5$.

Comment: I mean X_1 in a particular sample, sorry

Comment: What do you mean by "I mean X_1 in a particular sample"? You are using terminology so loosely it is hard to know what your questions mean, making it hard to understand your difficulty.

Comment: Let's say you measure the mass of an object $10$ times. The result of the first measurement is $X_1$, the result of the second measurement is $X_2$, and so on. Then $X_1, \ldots, X_{10}$ are all random variables and they are not all the same random variable (otherwise they would all have the same value).

Comment: If you like, you can say $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ are $n$ mutually independent random variables, all from the same (population) distribution. You may see the abbreviations _IID_ or _iid_ (for 'independent and identically distributed' for that.

Answer (score 2):

When you have an analysis or geometry problem with variables $x, y, z$ that all live in $\Bbb R$, you agree that these are three variables, right? It's the *exact* same here, except that every number and every interval is endowed with a "probability to occur". The fact that the distributions may be the same doesn't change the fact that the names are different and the variables are different (as soon as you don't have $X_1 = X_2$ almost surely).

Comment: @Arnauld Mortier so X is one random variable or X_1 and X_2 are all different. it does not make any difference, right?

Comment: @David What may be confusing is that there could very well be a r.v. called $X$ as well in the same text, in which case $X_1$,  $X_2$ etc. are usually assumed to follow the same distribution as $X$ (which is one way to consider sampling). It doesn't change the fact that $X_1$,  $X_2$ etc. are r.v.s in their own right.